# Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-oauth

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
Exception: Correlation failed.
Unknown location

Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler.HandleRequestAsync()

Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
Exception: Correlation failed.

Show raw exception details
System.Exception: Correlation failed.
Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler.HandleRequestAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Show raw exception details
System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
---> System.Exception: Correlation failed.
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

am using google auth, snd after deployinh the application and try to log in with google account, i gett his error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> I am using google auth, and after deploying the application and try to
> log in with google account, I get the error

Well, it would be nicer if you would have shared more details about your configuration and relevant code snippet. Because, when your application encounters error like below

> Exception: Correlation failed. Unknown location

Actually this error or exception may cause due to numerous issue.

First of all, the most common issue which leads to "Correlation failed" issue is your [CookieOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.cookieoptions?view=aspnetcore-7.0). If you have used cookie [SameSite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.cookieoptions?view=aspnetcore-7.0#properties) property to `SameSiteMode.None` you might get this error, because you are sending request to google auth endpoint so this might cause the issue. So please try by omitting `SameSiteMode.None`

Another important point is that, [RemoteAuthenticationOptions.CallbackPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-7.0#change-the-default-callback-uri) Because call back path is crucial and it notifies  the authorization middleware within  your app, on which URL-endpoint it should listen to, and after the request once auth provider gets back after successful authentication. Then the middleware itself will redirect the application to the callback URL defined in your login action within your project. So, please check your auth endpoint and callback path.

In addition to this, browser settings or configuration sometimes also can cause the above exception, within your browser please try by this option either in edge or in chrome://flags/ Disable "Cookies without SameSite must be secure" so you can change same-site "default" to "enabled" mode in chrome://flags? or . Which means HTTP and HTTPS can also leads this kind of exception.

**Note:** If you still struggling with the issue, [please refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-7.0#sign-in-with-google) and [also follow this blog post.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/upcoming-samesite-cookie-changes-in-asp-net-and-asp-net-core/)